# How can i sum up overlapping line features' attribute values from GeoJSON file?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a GeoJSON file containing a feature collection consisting of line features where each represents the section of public transport routes between two stops. For each section there's currently 24 different entities representing 1 hour of the day each and a slider that lets me display the desired hours features. On click on the feature (bus line segment) there's a pop up that shows me some of the attributes like total passengers on this segment in this hour.

[image: Hour selection and popup for line segments]

Currently, these attribute numbers represent *all* of the bus lines frequenting that specific segment (as per the GeoJSON attributes created by use of GeoPandas).

What I want to do however, is splitting the features up into the different bus line numbers. I would have a toggle function to display specific and multiple bus lines by selecting the respective attribute value.

Is Mapbox capable of letting me display overlapping features AND apply a math expression similar to "sum all where *segment_id* is equal* and display this in the popup ?

I thought of clusters, but can't conceptualize it well enough to make it work.

`cluster: true, cluster_id: 4, max: 50, sum: 100, has_island: false, point_count: 10`

Same thing with expressions `["+", number, number, ...]: number`: how do i apply this to my specific case ?

Thank you so much for any input !

Example of GeoJSON structure:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"time": 0, daytype": 0, "occsum": 57, "occmean": 19, "loadmax": 0.3332124289686858, "loadmean": 23, "name_start": "Bahnhof Tiefenbrunnen", "name_ziel": "Zollikon, Bahnübergang"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[8.56196881850715, 47.34937679929789], [8.565194360980028, 47.346512585317505]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"time": 0, "daytype": 1, "occsum": 30, "occmean": 15, "loadmax": 0.18583000846330552, "loadmean": 18, "name_start": "Bahnhof Tiefenbrunnen", "name_ziel": "Zollikon, Bahnübergang"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[8.56196881850715, 47.34937679929789], [8.565194360980028, 47.346512585317505]]}}
```

Full [html](https://github.com/VerkehrsbetriebeZuerich/vbz-flow-concept/blob/master/index.html) here,
Full [GeoJSON](https://github.com/VerkehrsbetriebeZuerich/vbz-flow-concept/blob/master/data/vbz.geojson) here (20mb!)